# I've uploaded an XML file and want to be able to filter data, then save it for the user

Tags: php, xml, wamp

this is my first Stack question. Please provide some criticism for the future posts I plan to do! I'm pretty new at PHP and feel I've scanned the PHP docs multiple times now trying to get a push in the right directions.

The goal of my current project is to upload an XML file, allow a user to filter that file by keywords and/or sections, save the new updated version and allow the user to download it.

I've got the upload an xml file and show it to the user. I'm confused on the next step of searching through this file, how do I access the file I've uploaded again? Is it a scoping issue or can I access the current variable?
Here's some code that shows you where I'm at currently. Please let me know if I'm missing anything appreciate ya.

This is the upload function.

```
<?php
// header('Content-type: text/xml');
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $filterSection = array(
        'path',
        'id',
        'title',
    );

    $file = $_FILES['file'];

    $fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $fileTmpName = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $fileSize = $_FILES['file']['size'];
    $fileError = $_FILES['file']['error'];
    $fileType = $_FILES['file']['type'];

    $fileExt = explode('.', $fileName);
    $fileActualExt = strtolower(end($fileExt));

    $allowed = array('xml');

    if (file_exists($fileTmpName)) {
        $xml = file_get_contents($fileTmpName);
        // $xml = simplexml_load_file($fileTmpName, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);
        require_once('function1.php');
        function1($xml);
        
    }
         else {
            echo "There was an error uploading your file";
        }
    } else {
        echo "You cannot upload files of this type.";
    }
    ?>
```

This is function1 which lays out the info in a table.

```
<?php

function build_table($array) {
    echo '<table class="gridtable">';
    echo '<tr>';
    $oneArray = ($array['item'][0]);
    foreach($oneArray as $key=>$value){
            echo '<th>' . htmlspecialchars($key) . '</th>';
            // echo "<form action='checkbox.php' method='get'> <input type='checkbox' name='formSubmit' value='Submit' /></form> ";
           }
    echo '</tr>';
    echo '<tr>';
    foreach($array['item'] as $item) {
    
    echo '</tr>';
    
        foreach($item as $key2=>$value2){
            if(is_array($value2)) {
                if(empty($value2)) {
                    //I feel this is extremely wrong line of code? Cant get the </variableclosingtag> to work as requested.
                    echo '<td>' . $key2 . '</td>';
                } else {
                    foreach($value2 as $key3=>$value3) {
                        if(is_array($value3)) {
                            
                                echo '<td>' . implode($value3) . '</td>';
                            } else {
                                echo '<td>' . $value3 . '</td>';
                            }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                echo '<td>' . $value2 . '</td>';
            }
    }
    }
    echo '</table>';
}

function function1($xml) {

    $data = simplexml_load_string($xml, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);
    $json_string = json_encode($data);
    $dataArr = json_decode($json_string, true);

    build_table($dataArr);
    print_r(build_table($dataArr), 'HEREHELP');
}
?>
```

I know this is a general question, I'm looking for a general answer. I don't want someone to write code for me, but push me in the right direction.
Appreciate yall.

XML FILE Being uploaded (All files should be the same for this project).

```
-<items>


-<item>

<path>https://www.companyb.com/content/dam/competition/datacenter/companyb-foobar-dc-persistent-memory-review-response-guide-.pptx</path>

<id>a1021019</id>


-<title>

-<![CDATA[Company B foobar DC Persistent Memory Review Response Guide]]>
</title>


-<description>

-<![CDATA[Company B foobar DC Persistent memory Review Response Guide details the review landscape and positioning vs DRAM & NVDIMMs. Content includes Company B Internal only material]]>
</description>


-<keywords>

-<![CDATA[foobar,Persistent,Memory, Samsung,Apache Pass, AEP, Crystal Ridge]]>
</keywords>

<filetype>pptx</filetype>

<filename>companyb-foobar-dc-persistent-memory-review-response-guide-.pptx</filename>

<binaryfilesize>3.60MB</binaryfilesize>

<thumbnailViewPath>/content/dam/competition/datacenter/companyb-foobar-dc-persistent-memory-review-response-guide-.pptx.renditions.cq5dam.thumbnail.319.319.png</thumbnailViewPath>

<detailViewPath>/content/dam/competition/datacenter/companyb-foobar-dc-persistent-memory-review-response-guide-.pptx.renditions.cq5dam.web.1280.1280.jpeg</detailViewPath>

<publishdate>2018-11-13</publishdate>

<expiredate>2020-11-13</expiredate>

<createddate>2018-11-14</createddate>

<createdby>admin</createdby>

<lastmodifieddate>2018-12-14</lastmodifieddate>

<assetOwner>Syona Someone</assetOwner>

<assetOwnerEmail>syona.someone@companyb.com</assetOwnerEmail>

<secondaryOwner/>

<secondaryOwnerEmail/>

<assetExternalURL/>

<linkurl/>

<numPages>1</numPages>

<contentType/>

<usagetype>etma759c80e8b7a4081b8f8f7e3376191f3</usagetype>


-<languages>

<language>English</language>

</languages>

<geos/>

<products/>

<environment>prod</environment>

<clients/>


-<datacenters>

<datacenter>DAM Datacenter|Competition|Other</datacenter>

</datacenters>

<iots/>

<pncproducts/>

<featured/>

</item>


-<item>

<path>https://www.companyb.com/content/dam/competition/datacenter/nda-companyb-mountain-lake-vs-amat-france-review-analysis-networking-comms.pdf</path>

<id>a1027038</id>


-<title>

-<![CDATA[CLX Vs AMAT france Comms Review analysis ]]>
</title>


-<description>

-<![CDATA[france Vs CLX, ~10 WL including EPC ]]>
</description>


-<keywords>

-<![CDATA[AMAT Networking Comms mountain Lake EPC ]]>
</keywords>

<filetype>pdf</filetype>

<filename>nda-companyb-mountain-lake-vs-amat-france-review-analysis-networking-comms.pdf</filename>

<binaryfilesize>1.60MB</binaryfilesize>

<thumbnailViewPath>/content/dam/competition/datacenter/nda-companyb-mountain-lake-vs-amat-france-review-analysis-networking-comms.pdf.renditions.cq5dam.thumbnail.319.319.png</thumbnailViewPath>

<detailViewPath>/content/dam/competition/datacenter/nda-companyb-mountain-lake-vs-amat-france-review-analysis-networking-comms.pdf.renditions.cq5dam.web.1280.1280.jpeg</detailViewPath>

<publishdate>2019-06-20</publishdate>

<expiredate>2021-06-20</expiredate>

<createddate>2019-06-20</createddate>

<createdby>admin</createdby>

<lastmodifieddate>2019-06-20</lastmodifieddate>

<assetOwner>Praveen Menon</assetOwner>

<assetOwnerEmail>praveen.k.menon@companyb.com</assetOwnerEmail>

<secondaryOwner/>

<secondaryOwnerEmail/>

<assetExternalURL/>

<linkurl/>

<numPages>1</numPages>

<contentType/>

<usagetype>etmc4c5e7132748472e9818c2966e681da5</usagetype>


-<languages>

<language>English</language>

</languages>


-<geos>

<geo>Asia Pacific</geo>

<geo>EMEA</geo>

<geo>Latin America</geo>

<geo>North America</geo>

<geo>People's Republic of China</geo>

</geos>

<products/>

<environment>prod</environment>

<clients/>


-<datacenters>

<datacenter>DAM Datacenter|Competition|Network Infrastructure</datacenter>

<datacenter>DAM Datacenter|Competition|AMAT x86</datacenter>

</datacenters>

<iots/>

<pncproducts/>


-<featured>

<featured>DAM Datacenter : Competition / Network Infrastructure,DAM Datacenter : Competition / AMAT x86,</featured>

</featured>

</item>
```

[image]

Comment: At a very high level, “filter an XML file” is very vague. Are you filtering node values, attributes, and/or elements? Let’s start there, and completely ignore returning anything. In fact, let’s ignore “upload”, let’s just say there is an XML file at a known location on the server, can you describe how you want to “filter” it? Is your XML well-formed enough that we can limit the scope of the “filter”, or can someone upload anything they can dream off.

Comment: so you convert XMl to json and then back to an array....why? Could you not simply, and more efficiently, just process the XML once as XML to build the table? The code that handles the uploads checks for the `submit` being present in the POST data but does not verify if there is a file uploaded.

Comment: Incidentally the following is incorrect: `echo '<tr>';foreach($array['item'] as $item) {echo '</tr>';` (starting on line 9 within `build_table` ) as it will generate multiple closing `</tr>` tags ~ which might explain the `Cant get the </variableclosingtag> to work as requested.`

Comment: Chris - Thats a great question chris, I'm gonna edit the above and add a snippet of the xml file. For the project every "item" should have the same layout, no uploading anything they can dream of.

Professor - I don't have a solid answer on the converting xml to json and back, this is what seemed to work and the answers/suggestions I found online. I think my thought was to properly show the data in a table form for whoever uploaded the file.
I'm going to add a small picture to show how the table is generated currently since I'm not following the line 9 error.
Thanks for helping everyone.